# In Neo4j find path from root to a node in a tree

Tags: neo4j, cypher, rdf, ontology, rdfs

I am using Neo4J neosemantics plugin to load ontology.
I want to find the path (all intermediate nodes and edges with their properties) from root of the tree to a particular node. What would be the best (optimal) way to get this information in cypher?
The nodes are connected through subclassof relationships.

Comment: did you try any Cypher query? I mean, you should start with something, no? Like,. what happens if you run something similar to `MATCH path = (:Node {name:'node name here'})-[*]->(leaf)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-->()
RETURN path` - indeed, you might adapt label and attribute of the start node and probably the edge label to the label of the subClassOf relation instead of `*` - and given that you want from root to a given node, maybe even switch the direction, currently it returns all paths from given node to leaf nodes. If the root node is `owl:thing` it should be even more simply and efficient

Comment: i am quite new to cypher, so was looking for the direction. this is quite helpful!

Comment: once you found the solution for your problem, feel free to post your final Cypher query as an answer here. Might help others for sure. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you import an ontology with neosemantics using the basic settings, you can get the path(s) between a class and it's parents all the way to the root with the following query. (I've imported the ESCO ontology):

```
MATCH path = (c:n4sch__Class)-[:n4sch__SCO*]->(root:n4sch__Class) //(1)
WHERE c.uri = "http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/74ce6ebc-8886-437e-bee9-ce5735aaa020"   // (2)
    AND not (root)-[:n4sch__SCO]->() //(3)
RETURN path //(4)
```

- in (1) we define the exploration pattern: follow SCO relationships all the way. That's what the asterisk means.
- in (2) we specify the starting class by its uri (
  although you could use a label or any other property)
- in (3) we
  specify that the root is a root because it's not the child of any
  other class
- in (4) we return the whole path. Great for visualisation in the browser [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFLMS.png). But if you want to return just a property of the nodes (say for instance the skos:prefLabel) in the path you can use this fragment instead: `RETURN [n in nodes(path) | n.skos__prefLabel]`